# How to copy file from tftp server to a network device?

Tags: linux, file-transfer, tftp

I have a linux machine.
I guess tftp server is running in it as I see the directory - `/tftpboot`. But I am not sure.
So how can I confirm this?

And I have a networking device which is reachable from the linux machine. (When I say reachable, I mean I can ping it)
Now I have to write bash script to copy OS image from my linux server to the networking device.
And I am thinking of using `tftp` protocol for file transfer between my linux machine and the networking device. How can I achieve this?

Note: I am avoiding scp since it asks for password and needs user interaction and sometimes on device reload the ssh related information would get changed and on the device forces us to make changes to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: you can check tftp daemon 1) copy /etc/hosts to /tftpboot 2) from unix try `tftp localhost -c get /hosts /tmp/hosts` if this work, then tftp is set up.

Comment: When I say, OS image it is the image we compile and build after we make some changes to the code. I work on embedded software developement for the networking device. So everytime we make the changes in the code and build an image, we need to load it into the device and test it

Comment: @Archemar when I tried the instruction you mentioned, I'm getting the response as `Transfer timed out`